# Finding multiple occurrences in SQLite3 database?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I am having trouble with my SQL Query to return all entries in a column which have occurred more than twice.
I have looked at other StackOverflow answers for trying to do this, and whenever I apply the same query to mine it just returns entries where the first character in the entry is the same.

For example, there are around 6 entries in the database which start off with a '-' and it returns all of them even though they are not identical matches.

Would someone be able to tell me where my query is going wrong? 
I would have thought that looking for duplicates would be a standard procedure.

Here is the query I am using:

```
SELECT name FROM subs GROUP BY name HAVING (COUNT(name) > 1);
```

Here is a sample of the output:

```
-Johnny-
-Lady_Gaga-
-Randy_Marsh- 
AJWesty
All_CAPS
```

NB: I am looking to find all the usernames in the database that occur more than once.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your query should already be working I think.  What about your current output seems wrong to you?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I was under the impression that it would return those that occur more than once. For instance, there are a couple of usernames in the database that occur more than once and I am looking to find those. If that makes sense?

Comment: Take a look at my answer below, if that would help.  SQLite doesn't "know" that `-Lady_Gaga-` is the same thing as `Lada_Gaga`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try stripping the dashes off the names column.  Here is one way to do that:

```
SELECT REPLACE(name, '-', '')
FROM subs
GROUP BY REPLACE(name, '-', '')
HAVING (COUNT(name) > 1);
```

But this approach runs the risk of removing dashes occurring inside a name.  To avoid this, we need to do more work:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN SUBSTR(name, 1, 1) = '-' AND SUBSTR(name, LENGTH(name), 1) = '-'
         THEN SUBSTR(name, 2, LENGTH(name)-2)
         ELSE name END AS name
FROM subs
GROUP BY
    CASE WHEN SUBSTR(name, 1, 1) = '-' AND SUBSTR(name, LENGTH(name), 1) = '-'
         THEN SUBSTR(name, 2, LENGTH(name)-2)
         ELSE name END
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this out.